# Is an elliptic curve a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am currently reading the book Analysis 1 from Terence Tao. The way he defines a function says that it should pass the vertical line test. Sometimes ago I came across an elliptic curve and saw that it doesn't pass the vertical line test. Is the elliptic curve a function ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the definition of the 'vertical line test' is please. And an example of the elliptic curve would come in useful too, so we can relate it to what you have seen

Comment: Follow the definition. If it does not pass the vertical line test, it's not a function. However, it may be possible to split an elliptic curve into parts that are functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a function. The definition of an elliptic curve is the set of all points such that $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$. That is, $E_{a, b, c} \equiv \{ (x, y) : y^2 = x^3 + ax + b \}$.

Let a solution $(x_0, y_0) \in E_{a, b, c}$. then by definition $y_0^2 = x_0^3 + a x_0 + b$,. So, $(-y_0)^2 = y_0^2 =  x_0^3 + ax_0 + b$. Therefore, $(x_0, -y_0) \in E_{a, b, c}.$ Hence, this will fail the vertical line test at $x = x_0$.

That is to say, an elliptic curve cannot be a function.

#### Some pictures of elliptic curves to see the symmetry along the $x$-axis:

[image: Pictures of elliptic curves]

Answer (score 2):

It's not the graph of a function, there is no $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that an elliptic curve is described by the set $\{(x, f(x)): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, but if you can parametrize it with some $\gamma: [0, 1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ you can see it as the image of a function.

Answer (score 1):

No, an elliptic curve such as $y^2=x^3$ is not a function. Even if we restrict its domain to $x \ge 0$, there are two points $(x, \pm y)$ on the curve for each $x > 0$. Similarly a circle such as $x^2 + y^2=1$ is not a function. The correct description for such curves is an [algebraic variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety).